# SQL: PIVOT on Trial Balance Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to get the below query to work but struggling to get the PIVOT function to work properly, generally with syntax errors or multi-bound errors depending on how I structure it. I'm totally new to the PIVOT operator so I'm not sure how to fix this yet. Right now the month/period pulls vertically like the below sample data and I'm trying to get this period/month field (fpr) as the horizontal column.

| com | fpr | led | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 144 | 1 | 5-325 | $2442 |
| 144 | 1 | 6-522 | $56757 |
| 144 | 2 | 5-325 | $4355 |

```sql
SELECT t.com,
       t.fy,
       t.ledg,
       b.pl,
       b.desc,
       ISNULL(SUM(t.Debit_$ - t.Credit_$),0) AS Total_$
FROM (SELECT  com,
              fy,
              fpr,
              ledg,
              CASE WHEN dc = 1 THEN amt_1 ELSE 0 END AS Debit_$,
              CASE WHEN dc = 2 THEN amt_1 ELSE 0 END AS Credit_$
      FROM dbo.mas31) AS t
     LEFT JOIN dbo.sam13 AS b ON t.ledg = b.ledg
                             AND t.com = b.com)
PIVOT (SUM(Total_$)
       FOR fpr IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) AS pt
```

Comment: Honestly, don't use `PIVOT`. Conditional aggregation is far less restrictive, and (in my opinion) the syntax is much easier to read.

Comment: If you're getting errors though, include those in the question. Also, don't forget to include your expected results for your sample data.

Comment: Side note: `DESC` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and should *not* be used for object names. If you "must" have an object that has a Reserved Keyword for a name, *all* references to said object must be delimit identified using the T-SQL (brackets (`[]`)) or ANSI SQL (double quotes (`"`)) delimit identifier. But, again, just don't use names that are Reserved Keywords (or names that need delimit identifier in general).

Comment: I see, didnt know about the DESC. It's actually [desc] in the system like you said so that makes sense now, I trimmed up a lot of the code/fields to make the question more lean in length.

Comment: Your issue is that there is no table alias just before the word `PIVOT`, also extraneous `)` at `dbo.mas31) AS t`. And you need to do `select pt.*`, you cannot reference any of the pivoted tables

Answer (score 1):

Do the calculation for the total in the source query.
And only select the fields in the source query that will be aggregated on by the pivot.

*(untested notepad scribble)*

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT m.com, m.fy, m.ledg, s.pl, s.[desc], m.fpr
  -- debet - credit = total
  , (IIF(m.dc=1, m.amt_1, 0) - IIF(m.dc=2, m.amt_1, 0)) AS [Total_$]
  FROM dbo.mas31 AS m
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sam13 AS s 
    ON s.ledg = m.ledg
   AND s.com = m.com
) AS Src
PIVOT (
  SUM([Total_$])
  FOR fpr IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) AS Pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the comments mention, conditional aggregation is pretty simple to read/manage and more flexible if you need to aggregate multiple columns, instead of just grouping by them like pivot would.

```
select 
    com, 
    led, 
    sum(case when fpr=1 then total end) as [1], 
    sum(case when fpr=2 then total end) as [2]
from (...) t
group by 
    com,
    led
```